# Get data attribute of a <td> when specific cell is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my HTML code.
How can I get the value of the data attribute when click the cell?

```
<td id = "orderIds" data-cids="213,431">orders</td>
```

What should I use to trigger an event when I click on the `<td>` cell?

Comment: Show the JavaScript/jQuery code

Comment: try `$("#orderIds").attr("data-cids")`

Answer (score 3):

Please check below mentioned solution.

```js
$('td').click(function(){
    alert($(this).data('cids'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <td id = "orderIds" data-cids="213,431">orders</td>  
  <td data-cids="23,43">12</td>
  <td data-cids="21,41">23</td>
  <td data-cids="13,31">34</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bind a click event handler by selecting cell using the [has-attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/)(optional) and get data attribute value using [`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method.

```js
$('td[data-cids]').click(function() {
  console.log($(this).data('cids'));
  // or use `this.dataset.cids` 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td data-cids="213,431">orders</td>
    <td data-cids="123,234">orders</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Nice, thank you, is `dataset.cids` wrong or why you don´t use this?

Comment: @frankwisniewski both would work .... Anyway I just added jquery aproach

Answer (score 1):

you need clicked cell data attribute so use of this will do the needful. use following snippet and it should work.

```
$('td').click(function(){
        var data = $(this).data('cids');
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

With pure js...

```
orderIds.onclick=function(){
  console.log(this.dataset.cids)
}
```

you can also use `$('#orderIds)` with jQuery